# Concatenate strings (originally binary) in 8-character chunks, 2 per row

Tags: c#, formatting

Here is the code I would like reviewed:

```
int lines = 4; //Example
string input = "81111111822222228333333384444444" //Example

//Use a StringBuilder to make it easier when producing the formatted code
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

//Loop through the ASM Hex code and extract every 8 character and put them in 2 by 2 rows
//Also add a NOP as needed depending if it's Odd or Even
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
{
    string tempString = input.Substring(i * 8, 8);

    if (i % 2 == 1)
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(tempString);
    else
        stringBuilder.Append(tempString + " ");
}

//End Code with "000000" or "60000000 00000000" if empty line, needed for Gecko
if (lines % 2 == 1)
    stringBuilder.Append("00000000").AppendLine();
else
    stringBuilder.Append("60000000 00000000").AppendLine(); //This would be True in this Example (4 = Equal number)

    //Return the result
    return stringBuilder.ToString();

//stringBuilder.ToString() = 
//           "81111111 82222222
//            83333333 84444444
//            60000000 00000000"
```

What I am doing is basically what the comments says. What might be worth knowing is that originally the string that I want to format is read from a file as hex.

```
//"hex" is "input" in the first part.
var ba = File.ReadAllBytes($"temp{i}.o");

string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba).Replace("-", "");
hex = hex.Substring(104, lines * 8); //Remove Garbage data and read only what we want (8 in length * rows of ASM)
```

I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way of handling the data more directly via that.

I don't think my approach now is bad, but it feels a bit "overkill". It feels like I could probably just read the data I want directly and split up the bytes or something. Sadly, I don't have the skills to know if that is something one should be doing in this case.

`lines` is an integer which contains the rows from a text. It's simply used for the formatting as one line = 8 characters of the wanted text (hex).

An example of hex text would be something like:

```
81111111822222228333333384444444855555558666666687777777
```

It's simplified so it's easier to tell (each Code starts with 8 in this example).

What I want it to turn into in this case would be:

```
81111111 82222222
83333333 84444444
85555555 86666666
87777777 00000000
```

And if (8xxxxxxx) actually took up both 2 lines in the row, I would add:

```
60000000 00000000
```

The original code is of no interested as it's completely different (Assembly). The only useful part is the rows of code because one row of Assembly = 8 hex characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate splitting the string into *bytes* from creating lines.

By following the Single Responsibility Principle it's much easier to optmize your code because you can focus on one unit at a time. Other benefits are: easier maintenance and easier testing.

*(I call it just byte because it's 8 elements long)*

Ok, so here you'll need two methods. The first one just creates a list of strings and can be greatly simplified because we can add each substring directly to the list.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Bytify(this string value)
{
    var byteLength = 8;
    for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i += byteLength)
    {
        yield return value.Substring(i, byteLength);
    }       
}
```

There are many other methods for *splitting* the string into batches but that's not the point. It's about the SRP. If you have separate methods you can exchange the algorithm for another one without breaking or adjusting everything else. The method creating the lines will still work because it doesn't need to know how you create the list, it just requires one.

Done. Now you can work with the `bytes`.

---

The other method can build the lines. With some LINQ it's very easy to create each one. Notice that I also flipped the condition to be `values.Count % 2 == 0` that I find is easier to understand.

```
public static string ToBytePairs(this IList<string> values)
{
    var text = new StringBuilder();
    var lineWidth = 2;
    var byteSeparator = " ";        

    for (var i = 0; i < values.Count; i += lineWidth)
    {
        text.AppendLine(string.Join(byteSeparator, values.SkipFast(i).Take(lineWidth)));
    }

    if (values.Count % 2 == 0)
    {
        text.AppendLine(string.Join(byteSeparator, new[] { "60000000", "00000000" }));
    }
    else
    {
        // There is line break at the and already so we need to insert this one before it.
        text.Insert(text.Length - 1, $"{byteSeparator}00000000");
    }

    return text.ToString();
}
```

As a bonus a faster skip extension so that the entire list doesn't have to be enumerated.

```
private static IEnumerable<T> SkipFast<T>(this IList<T> values, int index)
{
    for (var i = index; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        yield return values[i];
    }
}
```

The default `Skip` is not a super fast solution but it's enough for *short* lists. You can easily find [`Skip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35411248/235671) optimized for `IList` that uses indexes if your strings a very big and every second matters. Just don't optimize too much if you don't need to. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Example:

```
var input = "8111111182222222833333338444444499999999";
var bytes = input.Bytify().ToList();
bytes.ToBytePairs().Dump(); // Dump() is LINQPad's method.
```

Result

```
// 8111111182222222833333338444444499999999

81111111 82222222
83333333 84444444
99999999 00000000
```

or

```
// 81111111822222228333333384444444

81111111 82222222
83333333 84444444
60000000 00000000
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as expected.

lineWidth % 2 == 1 will always be true, so i assume you mean lines.Count()?

And Appending a Line each for loop to "lines" causes one extra row to appear if it's an odd number, which messes the result up:(

Comment: @Zerowalker you think this doesn't work but you didn't test it, did you? Of course it will be true for 2,but false for 1,line width means how many _bytes_ there are in a singe line. I mean what I wrote. The code is tested ans it's correct unless you can prove it wrong. It was your idea to append extra rows, not mine ;-)

Comment: I tested it several times:(
The result is wrong if bytes contains an odd number of lines.

Comment: Wait i think you misunderstood.

the "00000000" stuff is After the 2 by 2 row things.
It's not within the loop, it's after it's done.

Comment: @Zerowalker this could be, I will check this, but on the other side it isn't easy to understand ;-)

Comment: @Zerowalker you are absolutely right, it should have been `values.Count` and not `lineWidht` which is here always 2. I've fixed the code and added a new extension.

Comment: I'm starting to think that someone doesn't like me, another downvote without a comment? ;-|

Comment: A bit confused though about the fast skip method, i need to use IEnumerable, but it shows IList?

Comment: @Zerowalker the first extension `Bytify` returns an `IEnumerable`, to execute it you need to call `ToList` so that you can pass an `IList` to the next extension that will perform faster with a list then with a pure `IEnumerable` becasue it can be accessed by index and the normal skip would have to enumerate the entire list each time you call skip.

Comment: Think i managed to get it, it was the "this" thing, i needed to change a bit.

Anyhow, i never knew what "yield return" did, learned something totally new, seen it but never grasped it, now i kinda get it:)

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code in the `if` statements has some duplication. Instead of

```
if (condition)
    stringBuilder.Append("aaaaa");
else
    stringBuilder.Append("aaaaa" + " ");
```

you should write

```
stringBuilder.Append("aaaaa");
if (!condition)
    stringBuilder.Append(" ");
```

This saves you a line of code and, more importantly, clearly demonstrates that `aaaaa` is *always* appended (which is not that obvious from the current code).

Other than that, your code is fine. Just put it in a separate method and give it a good name, like

```
static string Reformat(string hexcode) {
    int lines = hexcode.Length() / 8;
    // Rest of the code
}
```

After that, go through all of the comments and decide which of them add value to understanding the program. Remove all the others. This will fit more code on the screen and let the reader concentrate on the code itself.

Comment: Wait a minute, this isn't true at all is it?
I don't use the same constant string, i use two different.
"00000000" and "60000000 00000000", so i couldn't have one always be true.

Okay i am blind looked a the wrong place -_-, still one appends a line.

Comment: @t3chbot Yes, it was me. I downvoted your answer since you redefined the term "byte" in a piece of code that is so close to shuffling bits and bytes around that it can quickly lead to confusion.